# C# function that sets a bool true after a period of time

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write a C# function that takes in a bool and a float and resets that bool after a period of time (determined by the float)?

Specifically i'm asking for something like this:

```
void reset(bool a, float b){

    ... After a certain time period determined by b
    a = true;

}
```

So then to reset any bool i can just call reset, passing in a bool and a float which determines the time it takes until the bool is reset

This needs to work for any bool, not one specific bool. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Could you explain what is the problem that has lead you to think at this solution attempt?

Comment: It seems a classic XY problem. What the problem are you trying to solve? Can you accept a blocking solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information to provide the full solution but here are some ideas:

1. Pass the bool by reference. Please check [Passing Value Types by Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters#passing-value-types-by-reference) from Passing Value-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)
2. Wait: a) with await Task.Delay b) with a timer c) start a new Task and don't wait for it here

Here's one way:

```
bool isRunning = true;


// _ = to avoid CS4014: Because this call is not awaited (...)
_ = CallMeAfter(() => isRunning = false, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

...

static async Task CallMeAfter(Action f, TimeSpan after)
{
    await Task.Delay(after);
    f();
}
```

Comment: async functions cannot have ref, in or out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check that bool value after the method is executed, you need to pass it as a reference (check here how can you do it: [C# Pointers in a Method's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653588/c-sharp-pointers-in-a-methods-arguments) ).

In the method body, you can use an timer to determine when to edit the bool's value (using the second parameter): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -3):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        reset(false, 228.10803f);
    }

    public static void reset(bool a, float b)
    {
        float totalSeconds = b;
        Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(b));
        if(a)
        {
            a = false;
        }
        else
        {
            a = true;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Value should be reset after certain time. Bool value is {0}",a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `totalSeconds` variable is never used, also I would go for `a = !a;` instead of `if else` statements.

Comment: This changes only the local a.

Comment: you can remove totalSeconds variable, but the solution works for you question