# Parameter type conversion from C/C++ to C#: "double*" to "out double"?

Tags: c#, c++, pass-by-reference, out

I need to convert a bunch of functions from C++ to C#. These have method declarations like

```
void foo(struct input data*, double* ret1, double *ret2)
{
    // if ret1 is not NULL, return something in it
    if (ret1)
    {
         *ret1 = SomeComplexAndExpensiveMath(data);
    }

    if (ret2)
    {
         *ret2 = MoreComplexAndExpensiveMath(data);
    }
}
```

When I convert that to C#, out paramters would normally be the preferred choice, but passing `null` to an argument declared as "out double" is not allowed:

```
void foo(input data, out double ret1, out double ret2)
{    
    if (ret1 != null) // Error.
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Using `ref double?` as parameter type also looks weird and causes additional overhead.

Is there a way I can maintain the nice simple `out double` parameter type while still not computing return values the caller doesn't need? Is there a way to know that the caller did i.e. `foo(input, out _, out b)` to indicate he doesn't need ret1?

Comment: what about using the Double.NaN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: Does it cause more overhead than the indirection you're already adding in the C++ case?

Comment: Have you considered breaking the function into variants with different parameter lists?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Thinking about it, yes. But the actual implementation basically has a bunch of methods that all end up in one "do-it-all" implementation which then uses the above approach. And splitting that one up is probably not so easy (or would cause code duplication).

Comment: Then I'd say that's the real root problem. Do-it-all implementations back you into a corner.

Comment: @ClémentJean: How do you mean that? I could use double.NaN as _output_, but not as an input on an out parameter.

Comment: just like `out Double ret` instead of `out double ret`

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: I haven't written that code. It's from an existing, pretty complex library and I thought this would be a straight forward task. Seems I was wrong.

Comment: Sadly so ;) I still think `ref double?` is worth considering though

Comment: Also how about returning a result object rather than `void`, encapsulating the calculations that were made, and providing a policy (even if that's just some `bool`s) as arguments to tell the function what to do?

Comment: Yea, that sounds eligible as well. The actual do-it-all method can probably be made internal, so that any extra arguments there don't really matter.

Comment: Sort of dupe ish of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2870544/4386278

Answer (score 1):

Check the [out documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). The interesting part is:

> Variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed in a method call. However, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

So it is assumed by the caller, that whatever you pass as a value is going to be ignored.

Latest versions of VS will tell you so if you try:

```
int prs = 1; // Will inform you of unessecary assignment of prs
Int32.TryParse("2", prs);
```

So the `out` declaration assumes that it will by default overwrite the value. Your best bet is to use the `ref` keyword if you want to simulate the same functionality.

Check [C# Pointers in a Method's arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653588/c-sharp-pointers-in-a-methods-arguments)

What is the additional overhead compared to the C++ solution?

Comment: If I used `ref double` I would have to assign a value by the caller. Of course, now I could define that I set it to NaN if I don't want anything back, but that's a bit an ugly assumption. If I use `ref double?` I need to write `double? tmp = null; foo(init, ref tmp); if (tmp.HasValue)... ` everywhere.

Comment: Technically, I could use pointers, but that's not so really C#ish.

Comment: Yeah, I get the frustration, but there's not much you can do. Unfortunately there are no inline declarations for `ref` parameters, so the extra lines of code seem mandatory.

Comment: By the way, interesting reads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171781/when-to-use-pointers-in-c-net and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types

Comment: I know the pros/cons of using pointers in C#. Using them on the interface of a library that was just converted to C# to be easily usable and platform-independent is not so much on the pro side ;-) But thanks for the links anyway.